# Black areas in glossy surface

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have three curved objects which I would like to render with a glossy surface. Unfortunately I can't figure out why my cycles render gives me these black areas. If I render the objects individually the black areas disappear so I assume its some kind of reflective interaction.

Would anyone mind explaining where I'm going wrong with this please? Any help would be very much appreciated. I'll try to link the .blend file if that would help.

[image]

Comment: Is that image your render? Yes the blend would help in this case.

Comment: Hi, yes that is the render. [Blend File](http://www.andyreedphotography.co.uk/Temp/BlenderTest1.zip)

Comment: What type of look are you going for on those objects? Just a solid color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I looked at your blend, and it was nothing more then the reflection of the shadow from the other objects.

First off I whent into edit mode, selected everything with <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, then on the tool shelf under the *Shading/UV* tab pressed the *Recalculate* button. Half of the normals were backwards.

The main thing I did was add a *Diffuse* node to your material, connected to a *Mix Shader*. The diffuse node gives the material a base color, regardless of reflections. Then mixed with the glossy node will add some reflections back to the material.
[image: nodes]
You really need something for the glossy shader to reflect off of, if you are going to get any reflections. A [HDR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15358/2217) is commonly used.

[Modified blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32809)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for explaining. I notice you also changed the point light source for sun. I had originally wondered whether they might be shadows but I moved the point light source around and it seemed to make no difference.

Comment: @AndyReed your lamp was not doing anything because the color of the world (white) was contributing nearly all of the light.

Comment: Ah, I see. That really does start to explain things. Thank you.